# Will it be changed after Apple's uid expires?

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-authentication, uid, apple-login

I'm using the apple login package on the flutter. You can get uidtoken in conjunction with firebase.
I'm going to save this uid Token on the server and manage the users.
Will a new uidToken be issued after the expiration time?

Comment: yes, newToken was issued

Comment: When a new token is issued, how can we recognize that it is an old user? 
@GHPrakash

Comment: Frank van Puffelen Thank you and sorry i`m very late

Answer (score 1):

Right now it is not clear to me what you mean by "uidToken", so I'll explain the two most likely things below. In future questions please [include the code that shows where you are stuck](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), as it is the easiest way to prevent confusion.

In Firebase Authentication:

- Each user gets a UID (short for user identifier) that identifies them. This will never change for a user. So even if they sign in on a different system, they'll have the same UID.
- Authentication state is kept in a short lived ID token. This token is valid for one hour (by default) and is automatically refreshed by the Firebase SDKs behind the scenes. So the ID token changes every hour or so.